# Plotting a function of numpy vector

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, vector

I want to plot a function of a numpy matrix

```
f = lambda X: X.T @ X
```

but I'm not sure how to proceed. I'm familiar with the method for multivariable functions, and the equivalent function with multivariable functions (along with plotting) would be

```
g = lambda x, y: x**2 + y**2
X, Y = np.meshgrid(
    np.linspace(start = -10, stop = 10, num = 101),
    np.linspace(start = -10, stop = 10, num = 101))
plt.plot_surface(X,Y,g(X,Y))
```

so `f(np.matrix((x,y))) == g(x,y)`, but I don't know how to extend this to my vector function. So how can this be achieved?

Comment: So at a point `(xi, yi)` what is the associated `z` value?

Comment: What is `X.T @ X` supposed to be? It's not valid python syntax, is it?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest that's matrix multiplication, new in Python 3. [See this documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#whatsnew-pep-465)

Comment: @unutbu `z = f(np.matrix((xi,yi)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is arranging dimensions. Your f seem to expect X and Y to be cast as a collection of vectors. But X and Y are two 101x101 matrices. So some rearranging and massaging is required. The good news is that using the `map` command below can be done to any function. The bad news - efficiency is elegance are probably not optimal.

This is what I would try:

```
Z = map(f, np.array([X.ravel(), Y.ravel()]).T)
Z = np.array(list(Z)).reshape(X.shape)
```

And then

```
ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that what is meant by `X.T @ X` is `numpy.dot(X.T,X)`, you may directly plot the result just as with any other function.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

f = lambda X: np.dot(X.T,X)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(projection="3d")

X, Y = np.meshgrid(
    np.linspace(start = -10, stop = 10, num = 101),
    np.linspace(start = -10, stop = 10, num = 101))
ax.plot_surface(X,Y,f(X))

plt.show()
```

[image]

However, in order to get the desired output from the question, the function depends on both x and y, so what is wanted is probably

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

f = lambda xi,yi: np.dot(np.dot([xi,yi],np.identity(2)),[[xi],[yi]])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(projection="3d")

X, Y = np.meshgrid(
    np.linspace(start = -10, stop = 10, num = 101),
    np.linspace(start = -10, stop = 10, num = 101))

Z = np.vectorize(f)(X,Y)
ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: `@` was added in 3.5, but is equivalent to `np.dot(,)`. While this approach works with this particular function, I was more interested in a slightly more general approach, as this break down for `f = lambda X: X.T @ A @ X`, where `A` is a square matrix of size `n≠101`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. For matrix multiplication the number of columns of the first matrix needs to match the number of rows of the second. This is rather a mathematical necessity than a question of implementation in some programming language.

Comment: Indeed, so I believe the input to `f` should be a list of grid points, not a matrix of the gridlines.

Comment: What exactly is the desired outcome?

Comment: The exact same result as your plot above when using `f = lambda X: X.T @ np.identity(2) @ X`, which is mathematically identical to your function.

Comment: I also realised your plot is incorrect, so it should not result in that plot. Mathematically `f = lambda X: X.T @ X` should return a paraboloid, not a saddle. So to be clear; `f = lambda X: X.T @ X` should return the same result with `np.matrix((x,y))` as `g = lambda x, y: x**2 + y**2` returns with `x,y`.

Comment: My plot is not incorrect. It's simply not matching your expectation. What you call `X` is something other than what is used in the plot above.

Comment: Sorry I thought that was clear, but `f` and `g` are equivalent functions in the question. `X.T @ T` is equivalent to `x**2 + y**2` in matrix notation.

Comment: I guess I finally understand the question. `X` is meant to be the tuple of the x and y coordinate? See if the edited answer is what you want.

Comment: Any feedback on this? Does it work for you, or is there something unclear?